# Get all posts that do not have a specific custom field without using a subquery

Tags: custom-field, database, sql

I need to get all posts that do not have a particular custom field, (e.g. `custom_field`).

The following query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "custom_field")
```

I try to avoid using subqueries if possible.  **How can this query be rewritten so it doesn't use a subquery?**  I tried writing it with a JOIN, but I don't know how to avoid joining the rows for post X entirely if a particular `meta_key` custom field is present.

For example, a naive attempt might be:

```
SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts p JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.id = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key != "custom_field"
```

However, this query simply avoids joining on rows with a `meta_key` matching `"custom_field"`.  Other rows for that post will still be joined.  We wish to get all posts that don't have a custom field with a `meta_key` of `"custom_field"`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way WordPress does it:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_field' )
WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL
```

You can do this with [`WP_Query` `meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'`.